# Google Analytics, limit a User to a date range

Tags: google-analytics

I know I can limit a user to a particular profile, but as a subset of that, can I limit them to a date range without having to create a new tracking number? i.e. I want the client to see 12/1/11->1/1/12 ONLY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not if you're giving them access to the Google Analytics reporting interface.

You could implement this yourself by building a client-facing reporting interface via the Google Analytics API, but it'd be a lot of work.